# Angular JS testing with external library like Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

How do you testing angular controller with external library usage such as google analytic event tracking. For example:

```
$scope.showVolumn  = function() {
  ga('send', {
    'hitType': 'event',          
    'eventCategory': 'Volume',   
    'eventAction': 'click',      
    'eventLabel': 'Interaction'
  });

  if($scope.native !== 'true')
    vm.showVolumnCtl = !vm.showVolumnCtl;
};
```

Run thought my test code this error appeard

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ga

I don't think you can inject ga in the beforeEach right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `ga` is a global, it's attached to the `window` object, so you use [`$window`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) both in your app and in your tests.

Just inject `$window` and then call it like so.

```
  $window.ga('send', {
    'hitType': 'event',          
    'eventCategory': 'Volume',   
    'eventAction': 'click',      
    'eventLabel': 'Interaction'
  });
```

This will work exactly the same as you have. In your tests just inject `$window` again and mock it as you like.

A quick example:

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_$window_) {
    $window = _$window_;
    $window.ga = function(){}; //mock as you need
}));
```

Comment: Glad it was useful. As a related note, after using Analytics myself in an app whenever I have any kind of global I now always use `$window` to inject it in my controllers/services/ecc. As you see it makes testing fairly trivial and also it feels much more as explicitly *requiring* a dependency rather than silently expecting it to be there/coming from the sky. And, btw thanks for the "Master", I am flattered.